# Using AFNetworking for asynchronous POST json requests

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I've been trying to use POST json using AFNetworking. After some research I finally got this to work

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
    //Some POST
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.test.com/"]];
    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:@"https://www.test.com/user/login/"
                                                      parameters:@{@"username":self.username.text, @"password":self.password.text}];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Print the response body in text
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
        BOOL *success = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

This is fine for demonstation purposes, but now I want to finally use NSDirectory to split out my json objects, so I tried doing something like this, but my app crashes whenever I enter click on the button

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
    //Some POST
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.test.com/"]];
    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:@"https://www.test.com/user/login/"
                                                      parameters:@{@"username":self.username.text, @"password":self.password.text}];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Print the response body in text
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
        BOOL success = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"yes!!!");
        }else{
            NSString *reason = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"reason"];
            NSLog(@"reason: %@",reason);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

## error

```
2013-03-08 03:27:34.648 test[18253:c07] -[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x888a6b0
2013-03-08 03:27:34.648 test[18253:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x888a6b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ce0012 0x111de7e 0x1d6b4bd 0x1ccfbbc 0x1ccf94e 0x24608 0x12e71 0x4a4453f 0x4a56014 0x4a467d5 0x1c86af5 0x1c85f44 0x1c85e1b 0x1c3a7e3 0x1c3a668 0x61ffc 0x21ad 0x20d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and not `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

Also you can use the `AFHttpClient` directly:

```
NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"username":self.username.text, @"password":self.password.text};
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[httpClient postPath:@"api/v1/user/login/" parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Print the response body in text
    BOOL *success = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self handleConnectionError:error];
}];
```

I would also suggest creating a creating only one instance of the `AFHTTPClient` using `clientWithBaseURL:` method.

Comment: rckoenes, thats because that is the only post example I could find. can you please elaborate it for me if you dont mind? what changes should be made to the existing code?

Comment: Also read the documentation on https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking it does explain how to correctly use the `AFHTTPClient`. Have a look at the `AFAppDotNetAPIClient` this will give you a good example on how to use the `AFHTTPClient`.

Comment: Thank you so much rckoenes. but what is handleConnectionError? also, do I not need [operation start]; anymore? and is this method asynchronous as well?

Comment: The `handleConnectionError:` is a method that I made my self, such a methods will handle the `NSError` and present the user with a message. Yes the methods is asynchronous.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. But I just tested this code. it gives me the same error as my code from above

Comment: Are you sure that you `[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];` add this line. This tells `AFHTTPClient` to use JSON. And add this as well: `[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];` By the way this is all in the `AFNetworking` example apps.

Comment: If you are still using your old code dit you also replace the `AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation` with `AFJSONRequestOperation *operation`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to send JSON object and getting back JSON data and parse it

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://MySite.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];
//[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
//[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"Ans", @"name",
                        @"29",  @"age", nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                        path:@"/testJSONReturn.php"
                                                  parameters:params];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"DATA: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data"]);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
}];

[operation start];
```

Might help

Answer (score 0):

with  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager you will add your request manager in my case i've done a POST Method with NSdictionnary as a parameters

```
[manager GET:url parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
```

with this line you can choose your Method / GET OR POST

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters= dic;
NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[url appendString: RootObj.root];
    [url appendString:@"/yourURL/"];
manager.requestSerializer=[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {      
}];
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain how this solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

another method, using AFHTTPRequestOperation:

```
NSString* path = "http://www.test.com/file.php";
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
//request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
//operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
}];
[operation start];
```